# get points of bezier curve in raphael.js

Tags: jquery, html, raphael

does anyone of you know how I can get the `start` and `end` point of a bezier-curve in Raphael.js?

```
paper.path(['M', x1, y1, 'Q', c1, c2, x2, y2]);
```

how can I get in the example above the values? I append 50 path's trough a loop to the body and save them in an array. Later I will catch the values of each.

I tried:

```
var bbox = patharray[i].getBBox();
console.log([bbox.x, bbox,y]);
```

but it only gives me the starting point. How can I get the endpoint as well?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your bounding box will not give you the start, but rather the top-left. Your start point will simply be the first x1,y1 value you specified, and the end will be the last x2, y2. Bezier curves go directly through their end points.

Comment: yeah fine, but how can I get the value x2, y2 if its unknown?

Comment: Well it must be known, because you provided them in your loop.

Comment: got it, just had to push the value in an array while the random nummer was created. thank you!